# JUnit test thread's operations order

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, junit

I Have a *Multi-threaded*, shared-taxi simulator that I implemented.

In addition to the threads that produce real-time activities and display the road-map, the projects contains the following threads:

1. A `MatchMaker` thread that runs a matching algorithm between taxies and passengers.
2. Each `Taxi` runs on its own thread, which calculates at any given moment the current position of the taxi and the shortest route to pick up and drop off all the passengers that the `MatchMaker` has matched to it.

I want to write a `JUnit` test to check the order of operations (*pickup, dropoff and route-changing*) that each taxi is doing.

My naive solution is to make each thread write to a log file after each operation, e.g.
`"Taxi <taxi-id> picked up <passenger-id>."` 
then reconstruct the order of operations from the log file. And finally, check if it matches my expectations.

However, I'm pretty sure that this approach is inefficient.
So, what is the correct/traditional way to test a thread's operations order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you test based on the outcome? So do the scheduled pick-ups eventually get to their location? Testing on outcome makes your test a lot less sensitive to future change since it doesn't rely that much on the implementation.

Comment: I have tested the outcome, but there are many different factors that may affect it.
And that's why I want to test specific algorithm parts separately.

For example, I created a scenario where 2 passengers are arranged on a route where it is clear who to pick up first and who to drop off first. Then I want to use it to do a `JUnit` test to make sure the operation order remains right when I make changes to the code.

Comment: @KfirEttinger if you want to test some internal parts, I would expose that sufficiently so that you can use it directly from a test without concurrency being involved. Combining functional logic with concurrency logic is a PITA due to number of permutations you need to deal with. I would think twice before conflating them in a single test.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. I'll probably have to make all sorts of infrastructure changes to do the "expose" thing but I think it's doable :)

don't you think my "naive" solution might be good?

Comment: I would do some basic unit tests to test your lower level logic. And some concurrency tests to see how the integration of the lower level logic + threading works.